Why a driver for LED bulb may not output enough current?
The driver shown in the pictures below, is for a little 7-watt LED bulb with 9 2835 SMD LEDs.


The IC used in the driver is MT7828C whose datasheet and “Typical Application Circuit” you can see here.
The light is not as bright as it should be, and also flickers a bit. All 9 2835 SMD LEDs are good because when I use a similar driver, they light up brightly. So the problem is in the driver shown in the pictures. I connected an ammeter in the circuit and powered it on. At the first moment, it drew 0.022 amps and quickly it decreased to 0.015 amps.
The resistors are good. D1 is good. I checked the capacitors. The input orange capacitor has a capacity near its 3.3 µF. The VDD capacitor (connected to IC) is near 1 µF. I changed the output capacitor to a 3.3 µF electrolytic capacitor.
The two parallel current sense resistors connected to the CS pins of the IC are 4.3 Ω in parallel. So, according to the formula at the beginning of the page 6 of the datasheet, the output current should be 0.06976 amps. Why is it not?

Is this a repair question? Is the supply just broken, or the LEDs broken?

@ justme It is not a repair question because I am not a repairer; I just want to learn. as I said in the post, the LEDs are good, and the supply is not broken but cannot provide the current that it should (0.06976 amps).

didn't you already ask this? ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/723145/this-driver-for-led-bulb-cannot-output-enough-current-and-the-light-flickers-w

If other drivers output correct current and work properly, it means this is broken, not completely but degraded so it can't output same current than others. Any component might be a bit damaged by heat. Perhaps transformer winding have failed insulation and part of the coil is shorted out. There could be a million of reasons why it does not give out current that it should. Based on your description, we can't answer what is the exact reason to provide you the correct answer.

Some 2835 LEDs are rated for 2.2W @ 3.4V or 647 mA with 2sqin of 2oz Cu 2x sided.
The MT7828C is rated for I=300 mA/Rs, for Rs = 4.3 Ohms I=70 mA or about 10% of 2.2W due to lack of heatsink.  Samsung's rated at 2W max
Your measurement of 15 mA (if accurate) would require an Rs = 20 Ohms.
From the schematic, the current detection includes the ESR of \$C_{V_{DD}}\$.

according to the formula at the beginning of page 6 of the datasheet, the output current should be 0.06976 amps. Why is it not?

In theory, this means the lamp is failing from poor ESR yet this was not stated. ( the lamp was failing!)
Spec Review
The VDD (Pin1) de-coupling capacitor (typically 1uF ~ 4.7uF ceramic capacitor)
This means ESR is from 0.1 to 1 Ohm typically.  If ESR is higher, it will be dim and unstable. The Hysteretic frequency is unknown as well as the slew rate which determines the BW and impedance of the ceramic.
Theory of Operation Review
With a high voltage rectified DC line and a low threshold current limiter using L to ramp up current, it is also affected by \$C_{V_{DD}}\$ as an LC series resonant. C goes to Vdd but is simulated to Gnd.

This is just my SWAG impression and is not accurate.

@ D.A.S. 1. I know that the 2835 LEDs of this lamp are at most 1W. So I=70 mA would be good for them. 2. The lamp is dim. I have no ESR meter. Can ESR of the capacitor be measured without ESR meter? If yes, how?

@ D.A.S. How much should the ESR of CVDD be in this driver?

@ D.A.S. Just for test purposes, I replaced the smd capacitor in CVDD, with a new 1µF 50V electrolytic capacitor. The output current increased to above 0.031 amps; but (1) it is not stable and fluctuates between 0.031 and 0.034 amps, and (2) the light still flickers. And of course the current is still half the amount it should be (0.069 amps).

1uF low ESR ecap will be around a few ohms try 10 uF low ESR although ceramic ESRxC=Tau is < 1% of low ESR e-cap. The ESR also causes the low flicker rate from the hysteresis  astable mode internal.R*C=k/f

I'm wondering who is learning from this analysis +1  ( to ask questions)

low ESR ecaps 0.5 us< Tau< 10 us, std ecaps >> 100 us.. X7R ceramic >1% of e-caps, NPO < 10% of X7R apply to most in smallish case sizes

@ D.A.S. I replaced the existing CVDD with a new smd ceramic 1uF capacitor. The output current of the driver did not improve and the light still flickered. Then I replaced a new smd ceramic 4.7uF capacitor. The same results happened. It seems, therefore, that IC is bad and is the cause of the problems of this driver.
